# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadEvents' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, calendar

i have the method code in a component called :

> user.service.ts

---

> import { CalendarComponent } from "ionic2-calendar/calendar";
>
> ```
>   @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCal: CalendarComponent;
>  addEvent() {
>     let eventCopy = {
>       title: this.event.title,
>       startTime:  new Date(this.event.startTime),
>       endTime: new Date(this.event.endTime),
>       allDay: this.event.allDay,
>
>     }
>
>     if (eventCopy.allDay) {
>       let start = eventCopy.startTime;
>       let end = eventCopy.endTime;
>
>       eventCopy.startTime = new Date(Date.UTC(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth(),
> ```
>
> start.getUTCDate()));
>             eventCopy.endTime = new Date(Date.UTC(end.getUTCFullYear(), end.getUTCMonth(), end.getUTCDate() + 1));
>           }
>
> ```
>     this.eventSource.push(eventCopy);
>     this.myCal.loadEvents();
>     this.resetEvent();
>   }
> ```

---

this is a form in a file called:

### > tab2.html

```
<ion-card>
        <ion-card-header tappable (click)="collapseCard = !collapseCard">
          <ion-card-title>Nueva tarea</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
       <ion-card-content *ngIf="!collapseCard">

           <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Describe tu tarea" [(ngModel)]="event.title"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Hora de inicio</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm" pickerFormat="MMM D:HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="event.startTime" [min]="minDate"></ion-datetime>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Hora final</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm" pickerFormat="MMM D:HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="event.endTime" [min]="minDate"></ion-datetime>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Todo el día?</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="event.allDay"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-button fill="outline" expand="block" (click)="addEvent()">AddEvent</ion-button>

        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
```

---

but this throws me the next error: 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LuEh.png)

How can i resolve it?

thanks!

Comment: initialize `this.eventSource = [];`  the error is at line 68 !